# SQL - Query MAX value given MAX value of different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table has three columns `[ID], [YEAR], [MALES]` and there can be multiple MALES values over multiple YEAR values for any given ID.

EX.

```
[ID]     [YEAR]     [MALES]
1        2010       10
1        2011       20
1        2011       35
1        2011       0
1        2012       25
1        2012       10
2        2010       5
2        2011       2
2        2011       11
2        2011       12
2        2012       0
2        2012       10
```

I need to query the maximum YEAR and the maximum MALES value for that YEAR for each ID. So the result for the example above would be:

```
[ID]     [YEAR]     [MALES]
1        2012       25
2        2012       10
```

Comment: Will all ID's have the same `MAX(Year)`?

Comment: No. MAX(Year) can vary between IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do this using `row_number()`:

```
select id, year, males
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by years desc, males desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I am really curious to see the difference in the explain plan between this answer and mine... Time for some testing...

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I needed. As a followup, is there a way to apply a filter to the row_number () over (partition... statement? For instance, I'd like to ignore all data where [males] = 0.

Comment: @cvdellen . . . You can add a `where` clause in the subquery.  Remember though that the sort is descending.  So, filtering out the 0s would result in the most recent year being filtered out, if the only value were `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with CTE as
(
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by ID order by year desc, males desc) as row_num
    from table
)
select *
from CTE
where row_num = 1
```

or

```
;with CTE as
(
    select ID, max(Year) as Year
    from table
    group by ID
)
select t.ID, t.Year, max(males) as males
from table as t
    inner join CTE as c on c.ID = t.ID and c.Year = t.Year
group by t.ID, t.year
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a sub-query to get the max year, then join to that to get the max MALES fro that year.

```
SELECT  T.ID
        ,SQ.MAX_YEAR
        ,MAX(T.MALES)
FROM    TABLE1 T
INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT  ID
                ,MAX(YEAR) AS MAX_YEAR
        FROM    TABLE1 
        GROUP BY
                ID
        ) SQ
ON      T.ID = SQ.ID
AND     T.YEAR = SQ.MAX_YEAR
GROUP BY
        T.ID
        ,SQ.MAX_YEAR
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want (your wording is somewhat difficult, but the example makes it look like you want my second one).

Maximum year for each ID:

```
SELECT id, MAX(year) FROM data;
```

Maximum males for each ID of maximum year:

```
SELECT id, year, MAX(males) FROM data WHERE year = (SELECT MAX(year) FROM data) 
    GROUP BY id;
```